# How to add extension method to the configuration instance in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, extension-methods, appsettings

*NB. This question is **not** about how to [implement extension methods](https://www.dotnetperls.com/extension).*

In the instance of *IConfiguration* that's pass in, I can access the connection string from my *appsettings.json* by the following syntax.

```
string azureDb = Configuration.GetConnectionString("azure");
```

I have a bunch of other parameters for the application stored in another section. Those are accessible by the syntax below.

```
string server = Configuration.GetSection("Smtp")["server"];
```

I'd like to set up an extension method so I can pick my settings in the same manner as is done for the connection strings. So I've set up a class with the following contents.

```
public static class Extension
{
  public static string GetSmtpServer(this IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    return configuration.GetSection("Smtp")["server"];
  }
}
```

However, that won't work because an extension method can't be assigned to an interface. How should I proceed here? I also sense an issue due to the class *Extension* being static. I've noticed it's a bit problematic to inject things into a static constructor.

Is it possible to add my own customization as they did it for connection strings? How?

Comment: _Can't be assigned to an interface?_ Why not? Have you tried that?

Comment: "However, that won't work because an extension method can't be assigned to an interface" - what do you mean by that? You can certainly declare extension methods with target types that are interfaces. It's very unclear to me what you're asking. What happens with the code you've written?

Comment: @DaisyShipton I guess I wasn't clear enough. In the sample, I had to make the class *Extension* static. But then, I can't use DI in it to pass an instance of *IConfiguration* because the static class doesn't get instantiated and can't receive any injected object in the static  constructor.

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff Yes, I've tried it, of course. However, my description might be a bit unclear. Sorry for that. Please take a peek at the comment I made to Daisy.

Comment: Yes, extension methods always have to be in non-generic top-level static classes. It's not clear which static constructor you're talking about, or how you expect DI to get involved. I'm afraid I just don't follow what you're asking.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I want the extension method to return something that's based on the dependency injected *IConfiguration* object. So I need to receive that object as .Net Core distributes it. Usually I'd get it in a constructor and store in a private field but this particular class is static - and I get stuck as there's no instantiation (so DI can't serve the config object). I want to mimic the behavior of *GetConnectionString* in the object but for other parts of the *appconfig.json* file.

Comment: Which particular class is static? The class with the extension method in *has* to be static, but it sounds like you need this somewhere else. Please edit your question to make it a lot clearer. It sounds like the problem has really nothing to do with extension methods, and everything to do with a mismatch between DI and how you're trying to use an `IConfiguration`.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'm not sure how to rephrase the question at this moment but I feel that you might be into something (i.e. this might be a case of wrong diagnostics). Is it possible to use DI in a static class (the one that carries the extension method)? My DI works great for the other classes (the ones that I instantiate). I guess the main question might be "*is it possible to inject into static classes?*".

Comment: I'd expect the answer to be "no". When would it do the injection? And how could it do so? Half the point of DI is to *avoid* global state, but it sounds like you're expecting it to *provide* global state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods are perfectly valid with `this` pointing to an interface. However, you need to ensure that the object, implementing the interface, is an actual instance or a `NullReferenceException` will occur.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My bad. Please let me retry. The problem I get by making the class with the extension method (as shown in my example) to a static one is that I can't make DI pass in an instance of *IConfiguration* then.

Comment: Use your IoC to resolve the type in the class WHERE YOU ARE CALLING the extension method. Then call the extension method on the resolved instance.

Comment: This did the trick! As a follow-up question I wonder if it's at all possible to dependency inject into static classes.

Comment: No. You cannot inject into static classes, as you don't have control over the static constructor. Neither the IoC does. However, there is a way to resolve types manually, but 1st, this is another question and 2nd - avoid that whenever is possible. The preferred DI method is constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing wrong is getting a section then trying to use [] syntax.

it should work like this:

```
return configuration["Smtp:server"];
```

Comment: I didn't know that syntax, so thanks for that. However, it's not the reason to my issue. The syntax I'm using now works well. The problem is that I somehow fail adding the extension method and at the same time get DI functionality in the class.